# What does aggregate do here?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a R script with following line:

```
KSData.dataset.abbrev = aggregate(log2FC ~ Kinase.Gene+Substrate.Gene+Substrate.Mod+Source, data=KSData.dataset.abbrev, FUN=mean)
```

KSData.dataset.abbrev looks like this:

```
    Kinase.Gene Substrate.Gene Substrate.Mod                          Peptide           p        FC       log2FC          Source
364        ABL1          RBM39           Y95                        YRSPYSGPK 0.019590948 1.6158045  0.692252615 PhosphoSitePlus
8          AKT1         AKT1S1          T246                         LNTSDFQK 0.800879536 0.8909224 -0.166628324 PhosphoSitePlus
121        AKT1          EPHA2          S897                    LPSTSGSEGVPFR 0.500658346 0.7052020 -0.503891606 PhosphoSitePlus
```

after using the code line above, the df looks similar to this:

```
    Kinase.Gene Substrate.Gene Substrate.Mod          Source        log2FC
430        ABL1          RBM39           Y95 PhosphoSitePlus  0.6922526152
19         AKT1          PEA15          S116 PhosphoSitePlus  1.1782441053
80         AKT1           MDM2          S166 PhosphoSitePlus -0.7967537534
```

I have no clue, what exaclty this line do...
Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you checked the manual: `?aggregate` in RStudio?

Comment: But How do I get only one `log2FC` value per row for three different groups? If I only use `Kinase.Gene` as group argument, it's simple. It groups them and calculates the mean. But If there is another group... Is the mean of the other group calculated with the mean of the first group to get only one value for the mean log2FC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I calculates the `mean` of `log2FC` for the *unique groups combinations* `Kinase.Gene`, `Substrate.Gene`, `Substrate.Mod` and `Source`.

Using a small data sample, you can see what `aggregate` is doing:

```
(tt  <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b=1:3, x=1:12))
#   a b  x
#1  1 1  1
#2  2 2  2
#3  1 3  3
#4  2 1  4
#5  1 2  5
#6  2 3  6
#7  1 1  7
#8  2 2  8
#9  1 3  9
#10 2 1 10
#11 1 2 11
#12 2 3 12

aggregate(x ~ a, data=tt, FUN=mean) #Average for the groups in col a
#  a x
#1 1 6
#2 2 7

aggregate(x ~ a + b, data=tt, FUN=mean) #Average for the groups in col a and b
#  a b x
#1 1 1 4
#2 2 1 7
#3 1 2 8
#4 2 2 5
#5 1 3 6
#6 2 3 9
```